# Swift Google Place Autocomplete to not auto dismiss when pressing background

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autocomplete

I'm wondering if its possible to not dismiss the whole search bar when any part of the yellow is being clicked (In the img link). When the search bar has no text to prompt the autocomplete to appear. I thought setting this to false might help :/

```
searchController?.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
```

And also, once I selected a result from the autocomplete list. I wanted the search bar to stay, but hide away the "dim" and results

```
searchController?.searchBar.text = place.name
searchController?.searchResultsController?.view.isHidden = true
```

but the dim is still there and i can't access anything in the background. Any help would be great! Thanks!

[Google search bar yellow background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a70f3.jpg)